# integer convert into time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

```
DocDate  DocTime  DocEntry  DocNum                CardName U_OrdrType  \
0  2019-01-01     1511         1  100001  xyz Company    Advance   
1  2019-01-01     1512         2  100002  xyz Company    Advance   
2  2019-01-01     1514         3  100003  xyz Company    Advance   
3  2019-01-01     1516         4  100004         xyz    Advance
```

Retrive dataq from SQL database in which time is in integer format (1511) I want to covert time like 15:11 Please also note that some locations midnight 12 indicate only (0) I want 0 as 00:00

Comment: Seems like a straightforward calculation. What have you tried so far?

Comment: if you would have it as string then you could try `df['DocEntry].str[:2] + ":" + df['DocEntry].str[2:]`. But if you have values like `0` then you will have to create more complex function - with `if/else` - and run it with `df.apply(function_name)`

Comment: if you have it as integer then divide it `hours = 1511 // 100`, `minutes = 1511 % 100` and format it as string - `f"{hours}:{minutes}"`

Comment: how do you get it from database? Maybe database has some function to convert it to strings `15:11`

Comment: @furas if OP has "0", just zfill to four zeros and str method works fine

Answer (score 0):

If you want it as strings then you can use `apply` to run own function which convert it

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'DocTime': [1511, 1512, 1514, 1516, 0]
}

def convert(val):
    hours = val // 100
    minutes = val % 100
    return f"{hours:02}:{minutes:02}"

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['DocTimeString'] = df['DocTime'].apply(convert)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
   DocTime DocTimeString
0     1511         15:11
1     1512         15:12
2     1514         15:14
3     1516         15:16
4        0         00:00
```

---

You could also use `datetime.time()` - so you could later simply calculate difference between times - but it may display it with `seconds`. But still you can use this value with `strftime` to generate strings.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data = {
    'DocTime': [1511, 1512, 1514, 1516, 0]
}

def convert(val):
    hours = val // 100
    minutes = val % 100
    return datetime.time(hours, minutes)
                         

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['DocTimeDatetime'] = df['DocTime'].apply(convert)
df['DocTimeString']   = df['DocTimeDatetime'].apply(lambda dt:dt.strftime('%H:%M'))
#df['DocTimeString']   = df['DocTimeDatetime'].dt.strftime('%H:%M') # doesn't work because it is not `Datetime` object

print(df)
```

Result:

```
   DocTime DocTimeDatetime DocTimeString
0     1511        15:11:00         15:11
1     1512        15:12:00         15:12
2     1514        15:14:00         15:14
3     1516        15:16:00         15:16
4        0        00:00:00         00:00
```

---

Eventually you could convert all values to string with 4-digits (so `0` has to be `0000`) and then you could parse it as `%H%M` without `:`

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data = {
    'DocTime': [1511, 1512, 1514, 1516, 0]
}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# convert to strings with 4-digits

df['DT'] = df['DocTime'].apply(lambda x: f"{x:04}")

# parse text as `%H%M` - and get only `time`

df['DT'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DT'], format='%H%M').dt.time


print(df)
```

Result

```
   DocTime        DT
0     1511  15:11:00
1     1512  15:12:00
2     1514  15:14:00
3     1516  15:16:00
4        0  00:00:00
```

Comment: I need output in timeseries not in string

Comment: first: you should say it in question at start - we can't read in your mind. Second: in answer you have example which use `datetime` or `to_datetime`.

Answer (score 0):

to handle the data as a time series, create a [datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html) column like

```
import pandas as pd

# 1 - assumed input / example
df = pd.DataFrame({'DocDate': ["2019-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-01"],
                   'DocTime': [0, 1511, 1512, 1514]})

# 2 - DocTime to string (could be integrated in the next step)
df['DocTime'] = df['DocTime'].astype(str).str.zfill(4)

# 3 - now we can create datetime!
df['DocDateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DocDate'] + ' ' + df['DocTime'])

print(df)
      DocDate DocTime         DocDateTime
0  2019-01-01    0000 2019-01-01 00:00:00
1  2019-01-01    1511 2019-01-01 15:11:00
2  2019-01-01    1512 2019-01-01 15:12:00
3  2019-01-01    1514 2019-01-01 15:14:00
```